# How do I stop the music compression in Adobe Flash

Tags: flash, adobe

I have inserted a MP3 file in the library.
When I publish my file; the sound quality is degraded.

How do I stop the compression?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are global sound settings in File > Publish > Flash menu. Here you can set the sound compression for all sounds in your movie.

Additionally, you can set sound compression for individual sounds when you right-click on them in the library and then select "Properties". "Default" means that the global settings will be applied. "Raw" means no compression at all but this is likely to result in a huge filesize.